# How to make avail of antlr package of odata-server-core as the latest version of 4.9.0 doesn't contain it?

Tags: java, maven, odata, olingo

We're using odata-server-core-4.0.0 in our code.But,as it has vulnerabilities in maven till the version 4.6.0,we are trying to replace it with the latest version,4.9.0.
But,we use antlr(org.apache.olingo.server.core.uri.antlr) package classes such as UriLexer,UriParserParser.AllEOFContext etc.,
Latest version odata-server-core-4.9.0 doesn't contain antlr package.
Can anyone please help how to substitute antlr package classes in our code?

```
import org.apache.olingo.server.core.uri.antlr.UriLexer;
import org.apache.olingo.server.core.uri.antlr.UriParserParser;
import org.apache.olingo.server.core.uri.antlr.UriParserParser.AllEOFContext;
import org.apache.olingo.server.core.uri.antlr.UriParserParser.BatchEOFContext;
import org.apache.olingo.server.core.uri.antlr.UriParserParser.CrossjoinEOFContext;
import org.apache.olingo.server.core.uri.antlr.UriParserParser.EntityEOFContext;
import org.apache.olingo.server.core.uri.antlr.UriParserParser.ExpandItemsEOFContext;
import org.apache.olingo.server.core.uri.antlr.UriParserParser.FilterExpressionEOFContext;
import org.apache.olingo.server.core.uri.antlr.UriParserParser.MetadataEOFContext;
import org.apache.olingo.server.core.uri.antlr.UriParserParser.OrderByEOFContext;
import org.apache.olingo.server.core.uri.antlr.UriParserParser.PathSegmentEOFContext;
import org.apache.olingo.server.core.uri.antlr.UriParserParser.SelectEOFContext;

UriContext context = new UriContext();
        UriParseTreeVisitor uriParseTreeVisitor = new UriParseTreeVisitor(edm, context);
        
            final RawUri uri = UriDecoder.decodeUri(path, query, fragment, 0); // ->0 segments are before the service url

            // first, read the decoded path segments
            final String firstSegment = uri.pathSegmentListDecoded.isEmpty() ? "" : uri.pathSegmentListDecoded.get(0);

            if (firstSegment.isEmpty()) {
                ensureLastSegment(firstSegment, 0, uri.pathSegmentListDecoded.size());
                context.contextUriInfo = new UriInfoImpl().setKind(UriInfoKind.service);
                
            } else if (firstSegment.startsWith("$batch")) {
                ensureLastSegment(firstSegment, 1, uri.pathSegmentListDecoded.size());
                BatchEOFContext ctxBatchEOF = (BatchEOFContext) parseRule(uri.pathSegmentListDecoded.get(0), ParserEntryRules.Batch);
                uriParseTreeVisitor.visitBatchEOF(ctxBatchEOF);

            } else if (firstSegment.startsWith("$metadata")) {
                ensureLastSegment(firstSegment, 1, uri.pathSegmentListDecoded.size());
                MetadataEOFContext ctxMetadataEOF = (MetadataEOFContext) parseRule(uri.pathSegmentListDecoded.get(0),ParserEntryRules.Metadata);
                uriParseTreeVisitor.visitMetadataEOF(ctxMetadataEOF);
                context.contextUriInfo.setFragment(uri.fragment);

            } else if (firstSegment.startsWith("$entity")) {
                context.contextUriInfo = new UriInfoImpl().setKind(UriInfoKind.entityId);
                if (uri.pathSegmentListDecoded.size() > 1) {
                    final String typeCastSegment = uri.pathSegmentListDecoded.get(1);
                    ensureLastSegment(typeCastSegment, 2, uri.pathSegmentListDecoded.size());
                    EntityEOFContext ctxEntityEOF = (EntityEOFContext) parseRule(typeCastSegment, ParserEntryRules.Entity);
                    uriParseTreeVisitor.visitEntityEOF(ctxEntityEOF);
                }
                //Todo need todo the parameters

            } else if (firstSegment.startsWith("$all")) {
                ensureLastSegment(firstSegment, 1, uri.pathSegmentListDecoded.size());
                AllEOFContext ctxResourcePathEOF = (AllEOFContext) parseRule(uri.pathSegmentListDecoded.get(0), ParserEntryRules.All);
                uriParseTreeVisitor.visitAllEOF(ctxResourcePathEOF);
                //Todo Need todo the parameters
                
            }
```